# vagrant provision shows spontaneous error

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I have a vagrant box of Wndows 2008 R2 doing some Chef basic set up. If I use vagrant destroy + vagrant up, it works everytime. However, even I did nothing change on my repository (cookbook/recipes/attributes/anything) , the vagrant provision sometime shows me error while sometime it is able to go thru.. can anyone give me how to debug this?

Here is the log when it fail:

```
Matthew-Tings-MacBook-Pro-2:base mting923$ vagrant provision
WARNING: Could not load IOV methods. Check your GSSAPI C library for an update
WARNING: Could not load AEAD methods. Check your GSSAPI C library for an update
[Berkshelf] installing cookbooks...
[Berkshelf] Using windows (1.7.0)
[Berkshelf] Using ohai (1.0.3) at path:           '/Users/mting923/Documents/workspace/Schneider/chef-repo/cookbooks/ohai'
[Berkshelf] Installing pingdom (0.0.3) from github: 'cwjohnston/chef-pingdom' with branch: '0.0.3' over protocol: 'https'
[Berkshelf] Using powershell (1.0.8)
[Berkshelf] Using base (0.1.0) at path: '/Users/mting923/Documents/workspace/Schneider/chef-repo/cookbooks/base'
[Berkshelf] Using chef_handler (1.1.2)
[Berkshelf] Using chef-client (2.1.2)
[default] Running provisioner: Vagrant::Provisioners::ChefSolo...
C:\opscode\chef\bin\chef-solo.bat
[default] Generating chef JSON and uploading...
[default] Running chef-solo...
[2013-01-09T23:09:02+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 10.16.2 ***
[2013-01-09T23:09:25+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[base::default]"] from  JSON
[2013-01-09T23:09:25+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[base::default]]
[2013-01-09T23:09:25+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [base::default]
[2013-01-09T23:09:25+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for vagrant-2008R2.nam.gad.schneider-  electric.com
[2013-01-09T23:09:25+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2013-01-09T23:09:25+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2013-01-09T23:09:25+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-01-09T23:09:25+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-01-09T23:09:25+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to C:/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-01-09T23:09:25+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook base not  found. If you're loading base from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

It is not happening all the time.. like this minute I type:
    vagrant provision
it works, while another minute I type the same thing.. it fails a above.. here is the chef-stacktrace.out I got from the vagrant VM:

```
Generated at 2013-01-09 23:09:25 +0000
Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook base not found. If you're loading base from another cookbook, make sure you     configure the dependency in your metadata
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/cookbook/cookbook_collection.rb:38:in `block in     initialize'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-6.14.0/lib/ohai/mash.rb:77:in `yield'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-6.14.0/lib/ohai/mash.rb:77:in `default'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-6.14.0/lib/ohai/mash.rb:77:in `default'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/run_context.rb:94:in `[]'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/run_context.rb:94:in `resolve_recipe'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/run_context.rb:84:in `rescue in block in load'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/run_context.rb:76:in `block in load'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/run_context.rb:75:in `each'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/run_context.rb:75:in `load'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/client.rb:198:in `setup_run_context'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/client.rb:418:in `do_run'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/client.rb:176:in `run'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application.rb:140:in `run_chef_client'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:224:in `block in run_application'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:216:in `loop'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:216:in `run_application'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/application.rb:72:in `run'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.16.2/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-solo:19:in `load'
C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-solo:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Matthew, can you paste here stacktrace dump?

Comment: Hi WB, I already include the stacktrace above... unless you means something else..

Comment: I just ran again (without changing anything... ), and this time it works again:

Comment: Isn't it because the path to cookbook is wrong? `Using base (0.1.0) at path: '/Users/mting923/Documents/workspace/Schneider/chef-repo/cookbooks/base'`. Shouldn't it start with C:?

Comment: @DracoAter C: is valid directory name (quite odd, actually), but right now is relative from where you run it. Maybe it should be /C:/opscode/.....?

Comment: I am using my Mac to run this win08R2 VM, so I believe the path is suppose to be like that way. What really bothering me is the same routine but vagrant only report error sometime but not always...